# Trigger Plugin on Business Process flow Change (D365/9.1)

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I've written a plugin which sets the actual stage name to an custom field. This works so far. But if I’m changing the process from the ui my plugin is'nt triggering and the stage name (=> in my custom field) is not updating.

My Step is "Update on phonetocaseprocess" and update on "new_myProcess". Both on attribute "activestageid".

Anybody knows how my step should looks like? If theres any question feel free to ask :-D

Comment: Works so far - it broke recently? Or working in certain scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your [community question](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/314251), you are switching to a different process & trying to capture the new `stageid` name of new process.

Earlier `processid` and `stageid` were stored in the same entity record BPF is applied and they are deprecated now. Later on Dynamics Product design changed & ability to abandon/resume option added. Also different teams can have different BPF at the same time on the same record.

To accommodate all this separate BPF entity created on the same name, to capture the instances per record & security role privileges can also be found.

So you have trigger the plugin on each BPF record creation/update to capture the stage name in its associated record. Workflow can also be used like Uma explained in community thread.